# Can very small currents be accurately measured using only standard analog electronic components on an IC?

Tags: current-measurement, photodiode, electron, transimpedance

Let's say, for example, that I have a photodiode, which produces electrons in response to the amount of light.

What is the theoretical lower limit that can be accurately measured only using basic components, like a transimpedance amplifier? Could it be possible to detect a single electron? Is it possible to accurately count and detect every electron produced by the diode? What are the limiting factors?

Comment: There are lots of shelves out there. An electrometer can do this. Electrometer-grade op-amps are available at quite modest cost (in relation to the full instrument, that is). Can you be more specific with your limitations?

Comment: I want to make the circuit on an IC, so I have access to mosfets, resistors and capacitors of any size and value up to where they become too large to be practically produced on a silicon chip.

Comment: You can buy commercial camera sensors made on CMOS that have RMS read noise of less than 1 electron (and across millions of pixels no less), so if you're working on designing an IC that is certainly possible at least for high end CMOS.

Comment: What is the meaning of RMS read noise of less than 1 electron?

Comment: An RMS error of less than 1 electron means that the sensor will count the number of photoelectrons generated with a root mean square error of less than 1 electron.

Comment: "Using off-the-shelf components" and "on an IC" are very different requirements. In any case, I think it depends on just what you mean by "very small currents" and "accurately." Another question is how much voltage across your current sensor is permissible. Detecting 1 mA at 1 V is going to be a lot easier than detecting 1 mA at 1 mV.

Comment: CMOS fab.... isn't even on a shelf, it's making the shelf?

Comment: Search terms: "uCurrent EEVblog",  "What's all this femptoamere stuff anyhow?"

Comment: Using off-the-shelf parts you can measure a lot, but you will have to be very careful! One way to improve accuracy "for free", with any sensor, for example, is to take a whole lot of measurements and average them together.

Comment: It sounds like you may be more interested in counting photons than electrons. Maybe a photo-multiplier tube is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

1 A => 6,24 x 10^18 electrons/s -> one must measure at least 10^-19 A or 0.1*attoAmp ...
For [information](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4998979).

"Yes", we "can". But use only a very very good "isolator". Or "spider web" design.

We can begin with an op-amp like [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp7721.pdf?ts=1660058473621&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F) or [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4530-1.pdf).

But before, one should read [this](https://assets.testequity.com/te1/Documents/pdf/keithley/KeithleyLowLevelHandbook_7Ed.pdf). §2.3.8 Using a Coulombmeter to Measure Low Current

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to accurately count and detect every electron produced
> by the diode?*

- 1 μA produces \$6.242\times 10^{12}\$ electrons per second
- 1 nA produces \$6.242\times 10^{9}\$ electrons per second
- 1 pA produces \$6.242\times 10^{6}\$ electrons per second

So, decide what current-range your photodiode has first. Then think about the chances of two or more electrons being produced in the same time-measurement window and you should be able to answer that yourself. Of course if your measurement method has decent enough resolution you might be able to detect multiple electrons in the measurement window.

> *What is the theoretical lower limit that can be accurately measured
> only using off-the-shelf components, like a transimpedance amplifier?*

Any answer won't stand the test of time; it might X this week and then 2X next week or next month or year. We try and produce answers that stand the test of time so I would say go and research this. It's basically asking for product recommendations and that's off-topic: -

[image]